# How to un-set chromedriver as system variable

Tags: windows, selenium-chromedriver

I am using a variety of different Chrome Driver versions for different automation projects.

Now I have been having some Chrome Driver related issues in regard to version in some of these projects, because it seems my system has a certain Chrome Driver version assigned to the system path.

When I go into my CMD window and type

```
 chromedriver -v
```

it returns a version.
Indicating that chromedriver is set somewhere.

I have looked into my set system vars and windows path var.
Neither show any reference to any Chrome Driver.

I wish to un-set Chrome Driver from my system and would not expect the chromedriver -v command to return any version.

How would I go about attaining this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end there was no set system variable called chromedriver, rather one called selenium that pointed to a dir containing chrome driver.

I removed this system variable and this solved the issue for me.